connect ETIMEDOUT on proxy
When I attempt to run the following code I get an connect ETIMEDOUT error
  import type { Proxy, ProxyList } from "./proxyTypes";
  import axios from "axios";
  import { SocksProxyAgent } from "socks-proxy-agent";

  const getProxys = async (): Promise<ProxyList> => {
      const proxyUrl: string =
          "https://proxylist.geonode.com/api/proxy-list?limit=500&page=1&sort_by=lastChecked&sort_type=desc";
      return (await axios.get(proxyUrl)).data;
  };

  const getRandomProxy = (proxys: ProxyList): Proxy => {
      return proxys.data[Math.floor(Math.random() * proxys.data.length)];
  };

  const proxyToUri = (proxy: Proxy): string => {
      return `${proxy.protocols[0]}://${proxy.ip}:${proxy.port}`;
  };

  (async () => {
      const proxys = await getProxys();
      const proxy = getRandomProxy(proxys);
      const uri = proxyToUri(proxy);
      console.log(uri + " - " + proxy.responseTime + "ms");

      const httpsAgent = new SocksProxyAgent(uri);
      const client = axios.create({ httpsAgent });

      client
          .get("https://icanhazip.com/")
          .then((res) => {
              console.log(res.data);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
              console.log(e.message);
          });
  })();

I tried using a vpn and running on cloud services. It should return the proxys ip to the console. An exapmle output of the current code lookes like
socks4://212.3.105.11:4145 - 3308ms
connect ECONNREFUSED 212.3.105.11:4145
but should look like
socks4://185.161.186.92:54321 - 993ms
185.161.186.92
